# What can re-formatting a corrupt disk do that chkdsk can't?

Tags: format, windows-10

if a computer (windows 10) is suffering from hard disk corruption, the standard suggestion seems to be to run `chkdsk` to fix it, and if that doesn't work try re-formatting.

Why? What can re-formatting do that `chkdsk` can't? Both will detect and mark bad sectors, so why might a re-format work when a chkdsk doesn't? Does the `format` command have some other tricks up its sleeve that `chkdsk` doesn't?

A bit of back-ground. I'm not actually asking for practical help fixing this issue, I've ordered a new disk and have resigned myself to a re-build. I'm more curious about what's going on under the hood. `sfc` tells me all my protected system files are good. `chkdsk` tells me I have corruption in a few files (maybe 1/2 a dozen files in total) and for unknown reasons `chkdsk` repeatedly fails to fix them. There are many similar threads on the internet, and by and large they all suggest that if a chkdsk doesn't work try re-formatting. I appreciate that `chkdsk` is trying to repair both the disk and the files, and `format` is basically starting from scratch again.

Does format do anything else, or is the suggestion "try a reformat", simply a last stab in the dark for a solution - a bit like the standard "have you tried re-booting?"

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix a problem related to bad sector, the data contained in that bad sector needs to be read successfully and rewritten in a new location. Failure to read will prevent the sector relocation. A format will perform only writes that do not require a read.

Comment: a format starts from scratch, deletes all data and doesn't write anything - or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Well, a format will write some basic data structure for the file system. The bad sectors are already marked as bad and will not be used. The bad sectors will therefore not cause errors anymore.